# MS Graph query - Encoding UTF-8 does not work at Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue related to the encoding.

```
$usermailactivitydetail = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -headers $headers -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

$usermailactivitydetail variable :

```
Ä°Ã§ test01 BÃ¶lge)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getemailactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

script:

```
$appid = 'APPID'
$tenantid = 'TENANTID'
$secret = 'SECRETID'
 
$body =  @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id     = $appid
    Client_Secret = $secret
}
$ConnectionParameters=@{
    Uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    Method ="POST"
    Body = $body
}
$connection = Invoke-RestMethod @ConnectionParameters
 
$token = $connection.access_token
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token




$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer "+ $token} 
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period='D7')"
```

thanks,

UPDATE :

```
$usermailactivitydetail = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -headers $headers

$result = $usermailactivitydetail.Replace('ï»¿Report Refresh Date','Report Refresh Date')

$resultarray = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $result
#Export result to CSV
$resultarray | Export-Csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -encoding utf8
```

Comment: `-ContentType` merely sets the content type of the request; it doesn't do anything to the server response, which (if the example is any indication) apparently lacks an explicit character set, or is even worse an `application/octet-stream`. Try writing the response to a file (`-OutFile`) and inspecting that. If all else fails that could be explicitly read as a UTF-8 encoded file, even if bouncing through a file is a tad inefficient.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getemailactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0#response-1) even state the `Content-Type` of the redirected download file is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @Zett42: yes, that's where I got it from. Not being able to test the API myself I didn't want to presume the example 100% accurate, though (wouldn't be the first time the finer details are changed after release).

Comment: @JeroenMostert  thanks for your help. Like you said I've tried `Out-File` too. But There are some strange characters inside CSV file. What's solution for this ?

Comment: I've updated my question. (under update section)

Comment: No, instead of `Out-File`, Jeroen meant the _parameter_ `-OutFile` of `Invoke-RestMethod`. This should give you the raw response. Then read this in using `$resultArray = Import-Csv PathOfDownloadedFile -Encoding UTF8`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) suggested, try to download to a file to prevent `Invoke-RestMethod` from trying to interpret the data and get the encoding wrong. The file will contain the raw response from the server. Then force the encoding when reading the file through PowerShell.

```sh
$tempFilePath = (New-TemporaryFile).Fullname
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -headers $headers -OutFile $tempFilePath

$usermailactivitydetail = Import-Csv $tempFilePath -Encoding UTF8

Remove-Item $tempFilePath
```

Comment: thanks man. now there are correct characters inside variable (`usermailactivitydetail `). But I am exporting as CSV file via Export-CSV (like ``$usermailactivitydetail  | Export-Csv "C:\Usage.csv" -NoTypeInformation -encoding utf8) Still strange characters inside excel.

Comment: @Arbelac What happens if you open the downloaded file directly in Excel? `Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -headers $headers -OutFile c:\Usage.csv; Start C:\Usage.csv`

Comment: like you said yes it works.